# How to compare substrings within a folder and an array with PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, directory, sql-like

I have a folder with 100,000 files (pictures) which are named by their UPC code (8 to 14 numerical digits) followed by an underscore and other digits:

```
000012345678_00_1
```

And I have a list of 20,000 unique UPC codes in a word document (separated by commas) which should match a fifth of these pictures (I also have this list in an Excel table).

```
000000000000, 000000000001, 000000000011
```

**What I'm trying to do, is to find matches between my array (the 20,000 elements list) and files in my folder so as to extract only those 20,000 pictures from the folder.**

I've started by cutting the file name up to the "__" so as to get only the relevant part of the file name:

```
$FName = ($File -split '_')[0]
```

To make things harder, I also need to add a wild card " * " to the elements in the array since some extra "0" at the beginning of the files name might have been added and are not present in our array. For example, this UPC in the array "05713901" refers to this file name "00005713901_00.png "; so to find matches I will have to use the "like" operator.

Then when I've found those matches, I'll just have to use Move-Item to a new folder or subfolder.

This is what I've started to code without any result:

```
$Directory = "C:path_to_my_folder";

$AllFiles = Get-ChildItem $Directory 

$FileNames = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;

foreach($File in $AllFiles)

{
    $FName = ($File -split '_')[0] 
    $FileNames.Add($FName)   
}

$Upc = Get-Content C:\path_to_my_word.docx

Compare-Object $FileNames $Upc
```

Comment: `Compare-Object` is only going to tell you whether the 2 arrays match exactly (which they won't, they're of different sizes), or which entries *don't* fit with your expectations.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! One more command that I now understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't read a `docx`-file using `Get-Content`, and even if it did, `Compare-Object` wouldn't work because your word file was a list over UPC-codes separated by a commas (a single `string` in powershell), while `$FileNames` is an array (multiple-objects).

Copy the UPC-codes from excel to notepad so you get a simple textfile with one code per line similar to this sample.

UPC.txt - Content:

```
000000000000
000000000001
000000000011
....
```

It would take a long time to run 100.000 files through a 20.000 `-like` test-loop each. I would create a regex-pattern that looks for either of the codes with an underscore at the end. Ex:

```
$Directory = "C:\path_to_my_folder";
$AllFiles = Get-ChildItem $Directory 

#Generate regex that matches 00001_ or 00002_ etc. Trimming leading and trailing whitespace just to be safe.
$regex = ((Get-Content -Path "c:\UPC.txt") | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Trim())_" }) -join '|'

#Get files that match
$AllFiles | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $regex } | ForEach-Object {
    #Do something, ex. Move file.
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Dest C:\Destination       
}
```

Or simply

```
$AllFiles | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $regex } | Move-Item -Destination "C:\Destination"
```

Comment: Do as you please. With 20k lines I would go for a file to keep the script clean and dynamic, but that's just me. :-) Remember to accept the answer your eventually go for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I had created the notepad document with the copy-pasted UPC-codes from Excel, but then decided instead that I was gonna copy-paste the 20,000 entries (with the commas) directly into powershell as an array!
Do you mind showing an example or giving a quick explanation of the move file cmd? When I used it, it moved my parent folder directly to C:/user!

Comment: Haha yes I realised that having a 82 pages long word doc in powershell wasn't going to help me keep a clean script! But I wasn't sure how to organise the content to get it from a .txt to an array until you told me :)

Comment: Updated with two examples.

Answer (score 0):

Save your UPC codes as a plain text file. As Frode F. suggested, copying them from Excel to Notepad is probably the easiest way to do it. Save that list. Then we will load that list into PowerShell, and for each file we will split at the underscore like you did, and trim any leading zeros, then check if it is in the list of known codes. Move any files that are in the list of known UPCs with `Move-Item`

```
#Import Known UPC List
$UPCList = Get-Content C:\Path\To\UPCList.txt
#Remove Leading Zeros From List
$UPCList = $UPCList | ForEach{$_.TrimStart('0')}

$Directory = "C:path_to_my_folder"

Get-ChildItem $Directory | Where{$_.Name.Split('_')[0].TrimStart('0') -in $UPCList} | Move-Item -Dest C:\Destination
```

Comment: How do you plan on handling "000000000" ?  Good to show him both solutions. I haven't tested it, but I think regex would be a lot faster than running 20k patterns 100k times.. :-)

Comment: After doing as you two suggested, I used the script you gave me but encountered an error with the Move-Item after the pipeline: Move-Item 
(Translating from French what PS's output:) PS complained that the entry cannot be linked to any command parameters either b/c the cmd doesn't accept pipeline or b/c the entry and its proprieties doesn't match any parameters that accept the pipeline entry:
 + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\..:String) [Move-Item] , ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Comment: @FrodeF. My example above wasn't the best one: in the excel list none of those UPC codes start by more than 1-zero (you can get either 88888888 or 088888888 but no 0088888888) (yeah I looked manually over the 20,000 entries ...).
I also have a bit of time ahead (long-office hours yay!) so I could run a 1-hour program if needs be.
But I'm mostly glad to have both solutions so as to understand better how PS work :)

Comment: Sorry! I forgot the `-destination` parameter (I used `-dest` in the code above) has to be named for this use... I've updated my answer and you should no longer get that error.

Comment: @FrodeF. You are completely right, a RegEx match would be faster to be sure. This way is just simpler for most people, and while slower it is functional.